# How do I create a Vuetify multistep form?

Tags: vuetify.js

I recall seeing such a thing a few months ago, but now that I'm looking at the API, I can't find it. I'm talking about a form which has multiple sections that show one at a time. Anybody know about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `v-stepper` component I guess. Here's the [Stepper Documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers).

Answer (score 2):

There is also a stepper as well as **Expansion Panel**. Maybe you're talking about it [Expansion Panel Documentation.](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels)